# Error on importing FAMIX Java model using the VerveineJ

Tags: pharo, moose-technology

I'm trying to import a FAMIX JHotDraw java model using Verveinej, but no success so far.

I'm facing a FAMIX.FileIndexedAnchor not found error. As far as I understood Moose is not finding the source files, am I right? So, where should I set the root source folder?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Error]

Adding some trace:

```
FMMetaRepository(Object)>>error:
FMMetaRepository>>elementNamed: in Block: [ self error: 'Element ''' , aString , ''' not fou...etc...
Dictionary>>at:ifAbsent:
FMMetaRepository>>elementNamed:ifAbsent:
FMMetaRepository>>elementNamed:
FMFutureElement>>with:name:
FMFutureElement class>>with:name:
MSEImporter(FMImporter)>>beginElement:
FMMSEParser>>Element
FMMSEParser>>Document
FMMSEParser>>basicRun
FMMSEParser>>run in Block: [ :bar | ...
BlockClosure>>cull:
Job>>run in Block: [ result := block cull: self ]
BlockClosure>>on:do:
Job>>run in Block: [ ...
BlockClosure>>ensure:
Job>>run
MorphicUIManager(UIManager)>>displayProgress:from:to:during:
MorphicUIManager(UIManager)>>displayProgress:at:from:to:during:
FMMSEParser>>run
MSEImporter(FMImporter)>>run
MooseModel class>>importFrom:withMetamodel:
MooseModel class>>importFrom:
MooseModel>>importFromMSEStream:
MooseImportFromVerveineJWizard>>validateImportation
MooseImportFromVerveineJWizard>>performTerminateButtonAction in Block: [ :bar | ...
MooseCustomTask>>basicRun
MooseCustomTask(MooseTask)>>runWithProgress in Block: [ :bar | ...
BlockClosure>>cull:
```

Comment: Not necessarily. The file might be damaged (AFAICT from the stack trace; I'm don't use Moose much). Where did you get the .mse from?

Comment: .mse file was generated by VerveineJ coomand line execution and I also tried through Moose context menu, generating another .mse, but got the same error. Any ideas? Perhaps, as you pointed out, the problem is on the file generation.

Comment: Are you using the prebuilt image from the website or do you load the code yourself? You could try using the .mse for JHotDraw from the [Pangea](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/pangea) repository to see if the error still pops up.

Comment: Oh, and it might help if you posted the top portion of the stack trace (you can copy the trace by using the icons in the upper right corner of the debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Doru on [Moose-dev list](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/pipermail/moose-dev/2015-March/022718.html) and Max Leske for the tips above.
Turns out the problem was regarding my Moose image version which does not supports FileIndexedAnchor. So, just move to Moose 5.1 and every things begun to work!